# Opening local files without input or drag-and-drop

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

Is it possible to open a local file (from .html file located on the PC itself) without XMLHttpRequest for random reading and maybe writing and without loading all the content to RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. `XMLHttpRequest` is not used for reading local files, but for sending requests to webservers.